# glewInit() "Missing GL Version" in CMake Release builds only

Tags: opengl, cmake, glfw, glew

I am building my OpenGL project using CMake with MSVC. It uses GLEW with GLFW. It runs fine when I build with `--config Debug`, but glewInit() fails when I run the build command with `--config Release`. I've tried both 64 and 32 bit builds, and it runs in debug but not release in both cases.

I've used `add_definitions(-DGLEW_STATIC)` in my CMakeLists.txt file to avoid needing `#define GLEW_STATIC` everywhere, but I've tried both and it doesn't make a difference.

I can see that the release `glew.lib` is getting produced (and `glewd.lib` gets produced for debug builds), and if I inspect the project properties in VS, the correct one is in the list of linker inputs.

I've tried with and without the window hints before creating a GL context.

There's something I don't understand going on here. Why is my GL version missing, only for Release build configuration?

---

EDIT: Adding minimum reproducible example (thanks [squareskittles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3987854/squareskittles) for the suggestion).

This is my `CMakeLists.exe file`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(Demo LANGUAGES CXX)

# Make sure GLEW gets built as a static lib
add_definitions(-DGLEW_STATIC)
option( glew-cmake_BUILD_SHARED "Build the shared glew library" OFF )
option( glew-cmake_BUILD_STATIC "Build the static glew library" ON )

# Build dependencies
add_subdirectory(glew)
add_subdirectory(glfw)

add_executable(demo demo/main.cpp)

target_compile_features(demo PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
target_compile_definitions(demo PRIVATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
target_include_directories(demo PUBLIC glew/include)
target_include_directories(demo PUBLIC glfw/include)

# Link dependencies
target_link_libraries(demo libglew_static glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})
```

It might be important to know that [glew-cmake](https://github.com/Perlmint/glew-cmake) is what is in my `glew` directory.

And `demo/main.cpp`:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Open a window and initialize Glew
    assert(glfwInit());
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); 
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(600, 400, "window", 0, 0);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    std::cout << "GLFW: " << glfwGetVersionString() << "\n";
    std::cout << "GLEW: " << glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION) << "\n";
    GLenum glewStatus = glewInit();
    if (glewStatus != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cout << "GLEW ERROR: " << glewGetErrorString(glewStatus) << "\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    std::cout << "GL:   " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << "\n";

    // Shut down graphics
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

My build commands are run from a directory just below the level of my CMakeLists.txt file. My debug build command is:

```
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Debug
```

If I build & run the debug executable, a window opens before terminating, and the output is:

```
GLFW: 3.3.0 Win32 WGL EGL VisualC
GLEW: 2.2.0
GL:   3.2.0 - Build 25.20.100.6617
```

And my release build command is:

```
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Release
```

If I build & run the release executable, I hit the `exit(1)` line, and the output is:

```
GLFW: 3.3.0 Win32 WGL EGL VisualC
GLEW: 2.2.0
GLEW ERROR: Missing GL version
```

---

UPDATE: I've tried linking with shared libs (dlls) instead of static libs, and was confirmed that the bug still reproduces.

UPDATE: I tried building a VS project from scratch with only my minimum reproducible case, manually specifying either the static or dynamic linkages, and it actually *works*! So it seems like it must be something with my CMake configuration.

Comment: It probably has to do with you forgetting to configure something to both Release and Debug builds.

Comment: @tomerzeitune I agree, but I can't figure out what needs to change - I can see that the appropriate .libs are built for glew and linked to in each case.

Comment: Can you try to remove the glfw hints and see what happens ? Maybe you failed to create a valid opengl context.

Comment: @tomerzeitune I have tried this. The only difference is that it then defaults to my highest supported version of OpenGL, which is 4.5, in debug configuration. Release builds still fail with the same issue.

Comment: Yes, it is much more clear to understand what is going on now.

Comment: @stett try to link to opengl32.lib and turn optimization off on Release config. Just trying to eliminate some things that can go wrong

Comment: @tomerzeitune Good idea. I did this by adding the following lines to CMakeLists.txt:

`STRING(REPLACE "/O2" "/Od" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE})`
`STRING(REPLACE "/Ob2" "/Ob0" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE})`

I confirmed in VS that the generated project uses the correct optimization flags. I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I could get release builds to run with the exact same linkages if I manually set up a project in VS. I diffed the vcxproj file that I manually created with the one generated by CMake to figure out the differences in release configurations. It came down to the `NDEBUG` preprocessor definition.

I don't understand why this definition causes OpenGL not to be found (I suppose that's another question, but if you can answer it here I'll award you the answer). If I add the line

```
string( REPLACE "/DNDEBUG" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
```

to my CMakeLists.txt file, I'm able to build and run in release mode!